# SECTION tag doesn't wrap H1 tag

Tags: css, html

I'm using `<section>` to wrap few `<articles>`.
I already read I can use one `<h1>` per `<section>` as well in `<article>`.

The tag `<article>` wraps the heading tags perfectly allowing me have many of them inside columns, article after article. The same doesn't happen with `<section>`.

My heading tags are overflowing the  area covering 100% horizontally.
I know heading tags have this behavior(break line) by default, but I'd like to make `<section>` wrap them as `<article>` does.

The heading tags are important for SEO, that's why I wanna find a way to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rgMK/

Comment: problem will be in your css file........

Comment: Can you show us your CSS please ? Plus, you may use `<h2>` instead of `<h1>` in your `<article>`, they don't have the same weight (but this won't change anything to your issue, obviously).

Comment: The HTML code looks fine. Please share your CSS please.

Comment: Sorry guys, the CSS is now there. I'm using responsive.gs framework but I didn't set any class from there.

Comment: We need to see more of the CSS, specifically all styles applying to the `<section class="region region-special-offers">` tag. Most browsers come with some sort of debugging tools. Open it up (usually pressing F12 on the keyboard) and see which styles are being applied to the `h1` tag directly inside the `<section class="region region-special-offers">` tag.

Comment: I'm using H1 inside the article because the weight of this tag will refer to the article, not the whole page...at least it's what I understood.

Comment: It's fine, we've got enought CSS. That was caused by a `padding` on `section`, as expected. See my answer.

Comment: region region-special-offers are being set by Drupal but I removed its standard CSS.

The inspector element doesn't show them because they don't exist(not linked)

Comment: I commented out the padding, but the problem remains the same.
The inspector element shows the first H1 taking the whole width then the other H1 (from another section)starting right below. Thanks anyway :)

Btw, I tried to put the CSS lines you posted as answer too, unfortunately didnt work

Comment: My goal is set two sections with H1 as columns -  I've created a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8rgMK/

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a padding, added on your `section` elements (and *not* on your `article` elements).

Add this CSS :

```css
header, section, footer, aside {
     padding: 1.25em;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
     display: block;
}
section {  /* ADDED */
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1.25em;
}

section > h1{
    font-size: 2.375em;
    margin-bottom: 0.50em;
}

article {  /* ADDED */
    margin: 0 1.25em;
}

article >  h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.500em;   
}

article > .content{
    padding: 0.625em;
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {
    background: #e74c3c;
}
article {
    background: #bdc3c7;
}
section {
    background: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<section class="region region-special-offers">
   <h1>Special Offers</h1><!-- This one overflows -->
   <article id="block-block-10" class="col span_2 block block-block">
      <h1>St. Patrick’s Day 2014</h1><!-- This other tag doesn't -->
      <div class="content"></div>
   </article>
   <article id="block-block-11" class="col span_2 block block-block">
      <h1>Weekly Package</h1>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Maybe I couldn't explain it properly...check it out http://jsfiddle.net/8rgMK/ is exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0):

As I was using responsive.gs framework, I forgot setting classes to sections to behave as columns. I just set the same classes from article to section.